# Changes not reflecting outside reactive environment?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm still learning reactivity in Shiny.

I have this bit of code:

```
env <- reactive({
        int3_summary<- dataset %>%
        group_by(age_group) %>%
        summarise(original_cvd_count = sum(as.numeric(s723d)),
                  meanSBP = mean(sb16s, na.rm = T),
                  meanDBP = mean(sb16d, na.rm = T),
                  new_cvd_count = 0)

        output$result <- int3_summary$new_cvd_count - int3_summary$old_cvd_count
})
```

However, I get an error saying "object 'int3summary' not found". How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (or at least *should not*) put `output$... <-` blocks inside of a `reactive` block.

Try this instead:

```r
env <- reactive({
  req(dataset)
  dataset %>%
    group_by(age_group) %>%
    summarise(original_cvd_count = sum(as.numeric(s723d)),
              meanSBP = mean(sb16s, na.rm = T),
              meanDBP = mean(sb16d, na.rm = T),
              new_cvd_count = 0)
})
output$result <- reactive({
  req(env())
  env()$new_cvd_count - env()$old_cvd_count
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue. Additionally, how would I modify a column of the table (env() here) if I want to ahead?

Comment: Just like you would normally, e.g., `env() %>% mutate(...)` (if using `dplyr`). This modifies it solely in the current `reactive` block, I'm assuming that's what you need. (It might help to imagine that `env` is a function such as `env <- function() return(mtcars)`, and then `env() %>% mutate(...)` makes more sense. This is a slight misclassification to say that, but if it makes it easier to realize what `env()` is doing in your shiny code, go with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are doing it kind of linke incorrect.
env should be your reactive value.

```
env <- reactive({
    int3_summary<- dataset %>%
    group_by(age_group) %>%
    summarise(original_cvd_count = sum(as.numeric(s723d)),
              meanSBP = mean(sb16s, na.rm = T),
              meanDBP = mean(sb16d, na.rm = T),
              new_cvd_count = 0)
})
```

After that you can call env to display e.g. in a data.table.Take care that env is now kind of a fuction and you need to call it with ().

```
output$result <- <- renderPlot({ env()
#here you can add more calculations to get your desired output 
})
```